# Is this minifigure with a white shirt showing a little orange monster worth anything?

Tags: minifigure-identification, value

I have a LEGO minifigure that I am unable to find anywhere on the internet. He has the classic smiling yellow head, with a white torso portraying an orange monster shaped as a 3D cube/hexagon, with little vampire fangs in its mouth and crossed eyes. He has simple red legs. Does anyone know how much it might be worth? I am thinking of selling it.

[image]

Comment: I've found [the legs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00&idColor=5#T=C&C=5) and [the head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cp01&idColor=3#T=C&C=3). I've been doing a few searches that would be guaranteed to get this torso, but so far, it doesn't appear, which makes me think the part is still from a third-party company. You should probably sell this on eBay... (don't sell it on BL, I don't think they allow third-party parts).

Comment: I agree, I looked through basically "all" torsos on bricklink and nope. Can't even seem to locate what this logo could be

Comment: Just to chime in with my contribution, I have cropped the icon on the torso and ran a reverse Google Image Search, but it has failed to turn up any relevant results. From this I guess the logo is not widely known, thus should be a one-off or at best a small batch. A high resolution, crisp image could help though, where the artwork is in the focus plane.

Comment: Everything apart torso has been available in multiple sets. The print on torso is odd though. Normally, for minifigure produced by LEGO, the best smiley you could get is a picture of another minifigure head with some face expression. So this print is some sort of logo. While LEGO produced some minifigures with prints for some special occasions this one looks to be custom (printed by non-LEGO) due to being just a logo, without mentioning any special names, dates or any other meaning being available on the same minifigure.

Comment: @mindstormsboi What do you mean? We still don't know anything about this minifig. It could be worthless or priceless.

Comment: @Aziraphale I'm guessing the minifigure is worthless because those legs and the head appeared in many, many different minifigs but that torso seems um, very rare since it's barely mentioned on the internet but many Lego fans simply hate clone-brands and would probably not accept the offer of that torso. But maybe on eBay they might, yet I still think the minifig is practically worthless.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I also think that it is not valuable. However, it could be a famous Japanese comic book character. So, ebay could be a bad advice since unknown pieces may sell at a very low price. This happened to me with a brick set I bought in South Korea. 1 Euro for a 500-parts set.

Comment: It's worth whatever someone will pay you for it.

Comment: The classic smiley head alone is selling on Bricklink for US$0.50 - 2.50 on average, depending on used/new and which style of stud. Some have sold for US$6.

Answer (score 5):

The whole minifig assembly reminds me of of those services that allow you to print your own image on a torso piece such as [Minifigs.me](https://minifigs.me/collections/minifigs-for-special-occasions?page=1).

[image]

I wouldn't be surprised if this minifig was made using the same service as I cannot identify the graphic. I suspect this minifig could have been ordered as a promotional item.

The actual parts themselves are so common that they might even be the cheapest parts you could get to make a minifig. The parts can be sourced easily for under a dollar assuming you bought the torso without a custom print.